# Trouble invoking a higher-level function

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I'm practicing Javascript on an online learning site and I'm having trouble understanding this asignemnt.
I want to implement a function called filter(not the native function) that takes an array and a function as its arguments.

The filter function shall call the function that was sent in as an argument, as many times as the value that is in the array, it that makes sense, and shall return a new array that only contains the array-values for which the argument function returned true. Also want to create an empty array inside the filter-function, and to add values in it.

```
filter([1, 2, 3], function (value) { return value > 1 })
```

...should as an example return `[2, 3]`

This is my code from a previous assignment, which is similar to this one but so far I'm stuck. I'm not sure what changes are needed to be made.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

function _filter(str){
    alert(str)
}

function forEach(arr,callback) {
    for(z=0;z<arr.length;z++){
       callback(arr[z])
    }
}

forEach(arr,_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to declare a new array inside your function and keep pushing the elements inside that, if it satisfies the `callback` criteria:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

function callback(n) {
  return n > 1;
}

function filter(arr, callback) {
  if (!(typeof callback === 'Function' || typeof callback === 'function')) {
    throw new TypeError("Callback is not a function");
  }
  const filteredArr = [];
  for (let z = 0; z < arr.length; z++) {
    if (callback(arr[z])) {
      filteredArr.push(arr[z]);
    }
  }
  return filteredArr;
}

console.log(filter(arr, callback));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do this, depending on what you can use.

E.g. with reduce:

```js
const filter = (arr, fun) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => fun(val) ? [...acc, val] : acc, []);
}
```

Or with a plain loop:

```js
const filter = (arr, fun) => {
  const res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const value = arr[i];
    if(fun(value)) {
      res.push(value);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the array, and use an if-statement to determine whether to add the item to the result of the filter:

```js
function filter(arr, cb) {
    const result = []
    for(const i of arr) {
      if(cb(i)) result.push(i)
    }
    return result
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(filter(arr, (el) => el > 1)) // [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.map() function too. However, as per the definition on MDN web docs, The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Here in the example, if you will log the output of the arr.map() then the returned array by the map would be like

`[5, undefined, 4]`

but in your case, you should not worry about it and can push the result into new array ( ie: filteredItems).

`console.log(filterArray(arr, callbackFn))` would return your expected output -> `[5,4]`

The main reason I have mentioned array.map here is it is extensive in nature and you may manipulate the output as per your needs. For example, if you need to show in output some indicator for the items which did not meet your callbackFn conditions then you can do that. Also, I am not a fan of for-loops so that is my idiosyncrasy too.

Hope this helps you and broadens your JS world :) Cheers !!

```js
let arr = [5, 1, 4]



function filterArray(arr, callbackFn) {
  const filteredItems = [];

  arr.map( (item) => {
    if (callbackFn(item)) {
      filteredItems.push(item)  
    }
  });
  
  return filteredItems;
}

function callbackFn(value) {
  return value > 1;
}

console.log(filterArray(arr, callbackFn));
```